# Highest total value of 15 items based on total budget from another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with 3 columns (Name, Value, Cost). I am trying to find a way to return 15 Names from the data set that provide the highest Value with a combined Cost of $200 or less.

Ideally, I'd like to return say the top 20 unique entries of the combination of 15 Names that provide the highest combined Value.

Example Data Set:

| Name | Value | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Steve | $15 | $7 |
| Rachel | $20 | $9 |
| Adam | $25 | $6 |

Comment: Sorry, my previous question was closed so I fixed the issues causing the closure and assumed that replies to comments in a closed question would not appear.

Comment: I still got. your comments and the issue is based on `character` vs factor column as `parse_number` requires character and not factor class

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is known as the Knapsack problem. Except for some special cases, this problem is known to be NP-complete ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity)). This means that there is no 'fast' algorithm that is guaranteed to give you the highest value solution.

Fast in this case can be thought of as 'significantly better than trying all possible combinations and keeping the best one'. This might be practical for a small dataset and a powerful computer, but could takes more than a week for a dataset with 100 names.

As you have specified the dplyr tag, the best you can probably do is pick those items that have the best value:cost ratio. Probably something like the following:

```r
output = dataset  %>%
  mutate(ratio = value / cost) %>%
  arrange(-ratio) %>% # sort descending
  head(15) %>% # limit to at most 15 names
  mutate(cumulative = cumsum(cost)) %>% # cost of names from best ratio to worst
  filter(cumulative <= 200) %>% # discard least cost effective names to keep total cost under $200
  select(names)
```

Comment: Thank you! So is there a theoretical way to get this to work as I want without the ratio? Must return 15 names with the highest sum value with a cumulative cost of $200 or less? Say I didn't need it to return every possible outcome, just the best one.

Comment: If you must have the best possible 15 names, then the only way to be sure is to iterate through all combinations of 15 names. I would implement this using for loops rather than dplyr.